# Inserted data automatically deleted from database after application is terminated

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to insert data into a table and then display that data in a `DataGridView`.

When I insert the data at runtime, the entered data displays in a `DataGridView` however after termination of the application, nothing is stored in my "mdf" file.

I am using piping method to store my connection string and setting the property "copy to output" of my mdf file to "copy always".

Does anybody know why my database is not retaining the data after terminating the application?

Code:

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("mycs").ConnectionString)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.Connection = con
con.Open()
cmd.CommandText = "insert into tbl_party_data (pname, paddress, ppan, pmobile, pemail) values ('" & txt1.Text & "','" & txt2.Text & "','" & txt3.Text & "','" & txt4.Text & "','" & txt5.Text & "')"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter _
                                   ("select * from tbl_party_data", con)
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
adp.Fill(ds)
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

Comment: Copy Always means that every time you start a debug session the MDF file is copied from the solution folder to the runtime folder (bin\debug OR app_data). Of course the insert operation happens at runtime in that database and not in the one inside the solution folder

Comment: You're inserting into party_data and selecting tbl_party_data? is one a view?

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/ You also should be wrapping your connections and commands in a USING statement. And probably a good time to get in the habit of naming your textboxes (and other controls) something meaningful instead txt1, txt2. When you have 30-40 textboxes you will want to slit your throat when you have no idea what number each one is.

Comment: thanks to all of you for quick reply. and it was a tbl_party_data instead of party_data. it was my typing mistake.

Comment: and i agree with sean lange, thanks.